# Json Array cannot be deserialized

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I would like to start by saying that I am not a developer and this is my very first time writing a code to this extend of complication (at least to me). Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

The idea of this program is to retrieve the employee user ID (or signature) from an API URL once the name has been entered.

I have a JSON String

```
[{"signature":"JDOW","firstName":"Jane","fullName":"Dow, Jane","lastName":"Dow"}]
```

I am trying to deserialize it to a collection. But I am getting an error. Can somebody direct me to the right way to fix this?

```
namespace TimeSheet_Try11_Models
{
    public class Employeename
    {
        [JsonProperty("Signature")]
        public string Signature { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty("FullName")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
       
        [JsonProperty("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

I a trying to convert using the following code:

```
uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;
var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);

Employeename status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employeename>(response);
```

The error I am getting is:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TimeSheet_Try11_Models.Employeename' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Yo're currently *not* trying to deserialize it to a collection - you're trying to deserialize it to a *single* `Employeename`. If you call `DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>` *then* it'll try to deserialize it to a collection - and I suspect all will be well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, I am not getting a red line under the whole statement : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response); saying that "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.collection.Generic.List<TimeSheet_Try11_Models.Employeename>' to 'TimeSheet_Try11_Models.Employeename'"

Comment: Well no, you need to change the type of your variable as well, because you're trying to deserialize to a collection. (Why you'd call that variable `status` when it's a collection of employee names is another matter...)

Comment: That fixed the error, thank you. I have another silly question (once again this is my first time programming). I originally had the statement string signature = status.Signature.ToString(); and the return signature. Now, there is a redline under "status" of course so what would I change it to?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to be a back-and-forth - and this isn't a productive way to learn programming. If you don't know the basics, you will be *constantly* fighting for every single line of code. I strongly advise you to start with a *beginner's* tutorial on C#, otherwise your progress will be very slow indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserialize the Json data for collection as:

```
var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);
```

or

```
List<Employeename> status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);
```

Another thing is that, no need to use attribute `[JsonProperty("anyProperty")]` with your properties. Json can be deserialized without using it in attributes.

After getting the deserialzed data in `status` object, any value can be fetched from that object as:

```
string signature = status.Select(js => js.Signature).First();
```

Similarly other values can also be taken from the `status`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string has square brackets (`[]`) around it, which means it is a collection of items.
This is why the Deserialiser is erroring.

You need to either remove those brackets to give just one employee object in the input string, or tell `DeserializeObject` that it is a `List` you are deserialising.

```
var converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);
```

Working Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mnYSh8)

Comment: That fixed the error, thank you. I have another silly question (once again this is my first time programming). I originally had the statement string signature = status.Signature.ToString(); and the return signature. Now, there is a redline under "status" of course so what would I change it to?

Comment: See in the fiddle - because the output from the deserialisation is a List, you need to get an item from it, by indexing with `[0]` before using `.Signature`